# python sphinx, generated html out of bound, format not well

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I use python-sphinx, the html is like this, content part exceeds the bound. How can I solve this problem?[image]

Comment: Don't put ``MassQuery.application`` in every title, when it's already mentioned once in the root title?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following option in conf.py:

```
html_theme_options = {
    "stickysidebar": "true"
}
```

This is a theme option for the "default" theme (which seems to be what you are using). It makes the sidebar fixed and horizontally scrollable, and long non-breaking text chunks don't intrude on the main content area.

See http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-html_theme_options and http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html#builtin-themes.